# PHP array count into a variable

Tags: php, arrays, echo

I have this array here...

$previousBalance2 and it has 17 records in it

I put that 17 in a variable like so..

```
$i = count($previousBalance2);
```

I echoed out the `$i` variable and got 17

how ever when I try this echo

```
echo $previousBalance2[$i]['total'];
```

It does not echo out anything (nothing gets displayed) and yes each record has a `total` and it is called `total` how do I fix my code so it will echo out the total of the 17th record (which is also the last record) or how would I echo out the last record of an array?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to print the last element of an array use the following code:

```
$last_element = end($previousBalance2);
```

Comment: going to try `echo end($previousBalance2['total']);`

Comment: THat won't work either, since you're running `end` on `$previousBalance2['total']`. Instead, you need to shift the `['total']` outside the brackets (on some PHP versions), or something similar to `$x = end($previousBalance2); echo $x['total'];`.

Answer (score 6):

Remember, arrays are zero based. This means that your first element is 0 and the last, in this case, is 16, not 17. `$i-1` will do it, or a more general solution is to use [`end`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php).

Comment: Just to extend, it's worth noting that `end()` will also work for arrays with string keys (or dictionaries, to be more precise), since the array keys are totally ordered based on insertion time.

Answer (score 5):

Arrays start at the index of 0.

```
echo $previousBalance2[$i - 1]['total'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Php arrays start at 0. So try this: $i-1 instead of $i in the brackets!

Answer (score 1):

echo $previousBalance2[$i-1]['total']?